# User authentification in express.js / Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authorization

I have a problem with user authentification in my app that runs on Node.Js / Express.Js

Basically, when the user logs in the main interface (html), they are shown a graph, which is obtained through an API path (/api/data/json), which also requires authentification through

`exports.auth = express.basicAuth(User.authenticate);`

in routes/api.js

I tried "telling" routes/api.js that the user is already authorized through passing it one of the `res.locals.user` parameters, but it didn't help...

So my question: is there any way in Node.Js to store user's login details in a session variable (like you can do in PHP for example), so that it's passed on to all the components when authorization is needed, to avoid users having to re-authorize when they access another part of the app?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The basicAuth middleware populates `req.user` with the username when authentication has succeeded. To check if user is authenticated at any middleware that comes afterwards e.g. in your `routes/api.js`, all you have to do is check if `req.user` is defined:

```
if (req.user) {
    // User is already auth'ed; provide secret data
} else {
    // Proceed to next middleware to provide a standard error message
    next();
}
```

Alternatively you can also redirect to another route with `res.redirect('/goToOtherpage')` or you can respond with an HTTP error with `res.send(401)` to signal `Unauthorized` to the caller.

Comment: I tried to do that but when I launch app.js with this check it says ReferenceError: req is not defined. I tried to implement a check of this kind: if (req.user && typeof req.user.userId === 'undefined') but it still didn't work...

Comment: Where are you placing this check? As I mentioned this check goes in any of following middleware or route handlers where you need to know if the user is authenticated. E.g. setting up the route for `/api/endpoint` you'd do: `app.get('/api/endpoint', function(req, res, next) { <req.user CHECK HERE> });`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will be of any use but you could hook into the HTML5 session storage. Here is an article going into it a bit more.

http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/21/introduction-to-sessionstorage/

Here is an example taken from the article on how to use it.

```
//save a value
sessionStorage.setItem("name", "Nicholas");

//retrieve item
var name = sessionStorage.getItem("name");

//get the key name for the first item
var key = sessionStorage.key(0);

//remove the key
sessionStorage.removeItem(key);

//check how many key-value pairs are present
var count = sessionStorage.length;
```